# Bitcoin dont start sync

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, daemon

My node stopped, bitcoin core does not start synchronizing. I opened the bitcoin log and found this error: Does anyone have a solution??

```
i2pd_daemon_1  | 05:58:04@64/error - SSU2: RelayIntro unknown router to introduce
i2pd_daemon_1  | 05:58:16@549/error - Garlic: Can't handle .....-......-AEAD-Ratchet message
i2pd_daemon_1  | 05:58:21@64/error - SSU2: RelayIntro unknown router to introduce
i2pd_daemon_1  | 06:02:37@67/error - Garlic: Can't handle .....-......-AEAD-Ratchet message
i2pd_daemon_1  | 06:02:38@67/error - Garlic: Can't handle .....-......-AEAD-Ratchet message
i2pd_daemon_1  | 06:05:06@549/error - Garlic: Can't handle .....-......-AEAD-Ratchet message
i2pd_daemon_1  | 06:07:30@378/error - Tunnels: Can't select next hop for .....-...........-...........-...........-...........-...........-...........-......
i2pd_daemon_1  | 06:07:30@378/error - Tunnels: Can't create inbound tunnel, no peers available
i2pd_daemon_1  | 06:08:17@549/error - Garlic: Can't handle .....-......-AEAD-Ratchet message
i2pd_daemon_1  | 06:15:36@67/error - Garlic: Can't handle .....-......-AEAD-Ratchet message
```

Comment: That looks like logs from the I2P daemon, not Bitcoin Core

Comment: CANT handle ECIES is inside the bitcoin log

Comment: Bitcoin Core doesn't use ECIES in any way or form.

Comment: i do stop and start bitcoin, its ok